# Weird problem with IE8 (but not IE7/Firefox/Chome) - content overflowing after Javascript used

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I'm working on a website for an insurance company - currently just on our test servers.
The page in question is here: http://easygap.testservers.co.uk/4/getaquote/

It works fine in Chrome, Firefox, etc. In IE7 the layout is messed up, but that's going to be sorted later on (we haven't finished the styling on the form anyway).

In IE8, however, when you click yes or no, the footer comes up and the right hand menu scrolls over it.

Not sure why this is, have tried adding divs with clear: none, etc.
Any ideas?

(Before I get any elitist comments about my code, I'm 18 and have only really just started out working for a company. Suggestions are very, very welcome however pointless flaming is not. Thanks.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>To fix this, simply add `clear: both` to `#content`.</strike>

Your site seems to have changed.

You can now you can fix it by adding `overflow: auto` to `#content`.

---

Soooo irrelevant, but you have this:

```
<div id="centre">
```

I would advise you to always use the American spelling "center" when it comes to web development, to keep it consistent with `text-align: center`, and friends.

Comment: That's great, thanks a lot!
Interesting point too, won't change it on this website, but have now changed it in my template file.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why, but I fixed it in IE8 with CSS:

```
position: relative; bottom: 0;
```

Attached to the div#footer.

Try it and see if it helps you out.